# Encrypt data in javascript with publickey and decrypt that with privatekey in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc, webcrypto-api

In ASP.NET MVC Core(.NET6) I must Encrypt data in client side with publickey that I call from server with Ajax and send this encrypted data to the server side to decrypt with privatekey.

Javascript code is as following:

```
(() => {
    const getPublicKeyButton = document.querySelector(".aes-cbc .publicKey");
    getPublicKeyButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        getPublicKey();
    });

    function getPublicKey() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            traditional: true,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            url: 'https://localhost:7203/Home/RSA',
            success: function (result) {
                encrypt(result.returnValue)
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                alert("Error has occurred..");
            }
        });
    }

    function getSpkiDer(spkiPem) {
        const pemHeader = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>";
        const pemFooter = "</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
        var pemContents = spkiPem.substring(
            pemHeader.length,
            spkiPem.length - pemFooter.length
        );
        var binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
        return str2ab(binaryDerString);
    }

    async function importPublicKey(spkiPem) {
        return await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
            "spki",
            getSpkiDer(spkiPem),
            {
                name: "RSA-OAEP",
                hash: "SHA-256",
            },
            true,
            ["encrypt"]
        );
    }

    async function encryptRSA(key, plaintext) {
        let encrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
            {
                name: "RSA-OAEP",
            },
            key,
            plaintext
        );
        return encrypted;
    }

    function str2ab(str) {
        const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
        const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
            bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return buf;
    }

    function ab2str(buf) {
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
    }

    async function encrypt(publicKey) {
        const pub = await importPublicKey(publicKey);
        const encrypted = await encryptRSA(
            pub,
            new TextEncoder().encode(document.querySelector("#firstName").value)
        );
        const encryptedBase64 = window.btoa(ab2str(encrypted));
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = `https://localhost:7203/Home/Decrypt?data=${encryptedBase64}`
        xhr.open("Post", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    }
})();
```

The HTML is as following:

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px">
    <section class="encrypt-decrypt aes-cbc">
        <section class="row" dir="rtl" style="float: right">
            <div class="row" style="margin-right: 40px; margin-bottom: 10px">
                <input class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7" type="text" id="firstName" name="message">
                <label class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5" for="firstName">FirstName:</label>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-right: 160px; margin-top: 30px">
                <input class="publicKey" type="button" value="GetPublickey">
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
</div>
```

C# backend code is as following:

```
            [HttpGet]
            public JsonResult RSA()
            {
                RSACryptoServiceProvider initialProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
                _privateKey = ExportPrivateKey(initialProvider);
                _publicKey = ExportPublicKey(initialProvider);
                return Json(new { returnValue = _publicKey });
            }



            public static string ExportPrivateKey(RSACryptoServiceProvider csp)
            {
                StringWriter outputStream = new StringWriter();
                if (csp.PublicOnly) throw new ArgumentException("CSP does not contain a private key", "csp");
                var parameters = csp.ExportParameters(true);
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                    writer.Write((byte)0x30);
                    using (var innerStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        var innerWriter = new BinaryWriter(innerStream);
                        EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, new byte[] { 0x00 });
                        EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Modulus);
                        EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Exponent);
                        EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.D);
                        EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.P);
                        EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.Q);
                        EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.DP);
                        EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.DQ);
                        EncodeIntegerBigEndian(innerWriter, parameters.InverseQ);
                        var length = (int)innerStream.Length;
                        EncodeLength(writer, length);
                        writer.Write(innerStream.GetBuffer(), 0, length);
                    }
    
                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length).ToCharArray();
                    outputStream.Write("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < base64.Length; i += 64)
                    {
                        outputStream.Write(base64, i, Math.Min(64, base64.Length - i));
                        outputStream.Write("\n");
                    }
                    outputStream.Write("</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>");
                }
    
                return outputStream.ToString();
            }


            public static string ExportPublicKey(RSACryptoServiceProvider csp)
            {
                StringWriter outputStream = new StringWriter();
                var parameters = csp.ExportParameters(false);
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
                    writer.Write((byte)0x30);
                    using (var innerStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        var innerWriter = new BinaryWriter(innerStream);
                        innerWriter.Write((byte)0x30);
                        EncodeLength(innerWriter, 13);
                        innerWriter.Write((byte)0x06);
                        var rsaEncryptionOid = new byte[] { 0x2a, 0x86, 0x48, 0x86, 0xf7, 0x0d, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };
                        EncodeLength(innerWriter, rsaEncryptionOid.Length);
                        innerWriter.Write(rsaEncryptionOid);
                        innerWriter.Write((byte)0x05);
                        EncodeLength(innerWriter, 0);
                        innerWriter.Write((byte)0x03);
                        using (var bitStringStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            var bitStringWriter = new BinaryWriter(bitStringStream);
                            bitStringWriter.Write((byte)0x00);
                            bitStringWriter.Write((byte)0x30);
                            using (var paramsStream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                var paramsWriter = new BinaryWriter(paramsStream);
                                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(paramsWriter, parameters.Modulus);
                                EncodeIntegerBigEndian(paramsWriter, parameters.Exponent);
                                var paramsLength = (int)paramsStream.Length;
                                EncodeLength(bitStringWriter, paramsLength);
                                bitStringWriter.Write(paramsStream.GetBuffer(), 0, paramsLength);
                            }
                            var bitStringLength = (int)bitStringStream.Length;
                            EncodeLength(innerWriter, bitStringLength);
                            innerWriter.Write(bitStringStream.GetBuffer(), 0, bitStringLength);
                        }
                        var length = (int)innerStream.Length;
                        EncodeLength(writer, length);
                        writer.Write(innerStream.GetBuffer(), 0, length);
                    }
    
                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length).ToCharArray();
                    outputStream.Write("<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>\n");
                    for (var i = 0; i < base64.Length; i += 64)
                    {
                        outputStream.Write(base64, i, Math.Min(64, base64.Length - i));
                        outputStream.Write("\n");
                    }
                    outputStream.Write("</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>");
                }
    
                return outputStream.ToString();
            }


        private static void EncodeLength(BinaryWriter stream, int length)
        {
            if (length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", "Length must be non-negative");
            if (length < 0x80)
            {
                stream.Write((byte)length);
            }
            else
            {
                var temp = length;
                var bytesRequired = 0;
                while (temp > 0)
                {
                    temp >>= 8;
                    bytesRequired++;
                }
                stream.Write((byte)(bytesRequired | 0x80));
                for (var i = bytesRequired - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    stream.Write((byte)(length >> (8 * i) & 0xff));
                }
            }
        }



        private static void EncodeIntegerBigEndian(BinaryWriter stream, byte[] value, bool forceUnsigned = true)
        {
            stream.Write((byte)0x02);
            var prefixZeros = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                if (value[i] != 0) break;
                prefixZeros++;
            }
            if (value.Length - prefixZeros == 0)
            {
                EncodeLength(stream, 1);
                stream.Write((byte)0);
            }
            else
            {
                if (forceUnsigned && value[prefixZeros] > 0x7f)
                {
                    EncodeLength(stream, value.Length - prefixZeros + 1);
                    stream.Write((byte)0);
                }
                else
                {
                    EncodeLength(stream, value.Length - prefixZeros);
                }
                for (var i = prefixZeros; i < value.Length; i++)
                {
                    stream.Write(value[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

The last part in backend is as following that decrypt the encrypted data sending from javascript:

```
    private static string _privateKey;
    private static string _publicKey;

    [HttpPost]
    public void Decrypt(string data)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        var asdsw = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(asdsw);
        using var privateKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        privateKey.FromXmlString(_privateKey);
        var decryptedBytes = privateKey.Decrypt(encrypted, false);
        var dectryptedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
    }
```

when the Decrypt method is called then the error **'The length of the data to decrypt is not valid for the size of this key.'**
will be raised in the following code:

> var decryptedBytes = privateKey.Decrypt(encrypted, false);

How can I solve this problem? Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Probably problem is with padding, when you encrypt something its actually put into "containers" (its easier to imagine it like that, its not actual containers) of fixed size. Its the size of the key usually. Then comes the question what happens with last container - it should be padded up until uniform size to trick man in the middle about actual size of data. Your js client just need to enable padding. Look at this example on github - https://gist.github.com/marcus7777/c2753942505e99f82d916d93b4316b6f. In this example padding is with zeros, so in C# you should also specify that its zeros.

Comment: Hello friend. I cannot understand what do you mean. I put all my code here. Would you please explain it clearly? Is it possible for you to create a new project and use my code then solve the problem?

Comment: Im not expert in js sadly, but C# tells you exactly the problem - your encrypted string should satisfy this clause:  size(encryptedData) % size(publicKey) == 0. So just prepend it with zeros. Then remove them by specifying Padding = Padding.Zeros in C# server